# TwinCAT Systemtime-Timestruct to milliseconds since epoch

Tags: twincat, structured-text

I need to convert the timestruct I get from Beckhoffs function block "FB_LocalSystemTime" to milliseconds since epoch to receive the local computer time in milliseconds.

Unfortunately I can't find a function to convert this timestruct. Any help is appreciated.

```
//Local Systemtime variables
fbTime : FB_LocalSystemTime := ( bEnable := TRUE, dwCycle := 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `DT_TO_DINT` after converting the `TIMESTRUCT` to `DT`. This should give you seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

EDIT:
This code should give you milliseconds since 1/1/1970.

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    fbTime: FB_LocalSystemTime;
    tStruct: TIMESTRUCT;
    msec: DINT;
    dTime: DATE_AND_TIME;
    eTime_sec: DINT;
    eTime_msec: LINT;
END_VAR
```

```
fbTime(bEnable:=TRUE, dwCycle:=1, SystemTime=>tStruct);

msec := tStruct.wMilliseconds;
tStruct.wMilliseconds := 0;

dTime := SYSTEMTIME_TO_DT(tStruct);
eTime_sec := DT_TO_DINT(dTime);
eTime_msec := DINT_TO_LINT(eTime_sec) * 1000 + msec;
```

Comment: LINT is not supported in some PLC development systems, such as TwinCat.

Comment: `LINT` is supported in TwinCAT 3, perhaps not in TC2. The code I posted runs fine in 3.1 build 4024.12.

Answer (score 2):

You will get miliseconds with this function:

```
FUNCTION F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT : TIMESTRUCT
VAR
    fbGetSystemTime : GETSYSTEMTIME;    (*timestamp*)
    fileTime        : T_FILETIME;
    sDT: STRING(30);
END_VAR
```

```
fbGetSystemTime(timeLoDW => fileTime.dwLowDateTime, timeHiDW => fileTime.dwHighDateTime);
sDT := SYSTEMTIME_TO_STRING(FILETIME_TO_SYSTEMTIME(fileTime));

F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT.wYear := STRING_TO_WORD(LEFT(sDt, 4));
F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT.wMonth := STRING_TO_WORD(MID(sDt, 2, 6));
F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT.wDay := STRING_TO_WORD(MID(sDt, 2, 9));
F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT.wHour := STRING_TO_WORD(MID(sDt, 2, 12));
F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT.wMinute := STRING_TO_WORD(MID(sDt, 2, 15));
F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT.wSecond := STRING_TO_WORD(MID(sDt, 2, 18));
F_SYSTEMTIME_TO_TIMESTRUCT.wMilliseconds := STRING_TO_WORD(RIGHT(sDt, 3));
```

Comment: You can use [`SYSTEMTIME_TO_DT()`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibutilities/html/TcPlcLibUtilities_DT_TO_SYSTEMTIME.htm&id=) for this.

Comment: how do you get the miliseconds? The most significant digit for DT is one second

Comment: That is true. Sorry. Still you could use the `SYSTEMTIME_TO_DT` for all except the ms, right? That will save you a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SYSTEMTIME_TO_DT()` function to convert a timestruct to dt which is a 4byte `DATE_AND_TIME` data type.

The smallest unit of this data type is a second though and not a millisecond.
Given that `TIMESTRUCT` has a millisecond value in it, you can easily use it and concatenate everything to a human readable string.

Comment: Just one (sometimes important) note: The `SYSTEMTIME_TO_DT` [rounds milliseconds to nearest second](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/9007199289893899.html?id=6847227180317996074), which can cause something that you don't want. For example, if time is 17:52:10.600, the DT would be 17:52:11. But if you really think about it, it should be 17:52:10. This can be fixed by setting the `TIMESTRUCT` value 
`wMilliseconds` to 0 before conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I've used function `GetSystemTime()` which returns number of 100ns since 1 January 1601 (god knows why). So we just need to shift up to 1/1/1970 by add `11644473600_000_000_0` (which is amount od 100ns periods between dates) and then convert 100ns periods to e.g. miliseconds by divide over `1000_0` or seconds by divide them over `1_000_000_0`. Remember that's a UTC time, if You want to get local time use FB_LocalSystemTime and timestruct conversion as **@kolyur** mentioned.

```
FUNCTION GET_UNIX_EPOCH : ULINT
```

```
GET_UNIX_EPOCH := (F_GetSystemTime() - 116444736000000000) / 10000;
```